# Check if physical directory exists issue 403 with PHP

Tags: php, apache

I have, just as any site would some physical directories (a.e. images, css, includes and so on), but my system also creates virtual directories for categories and pages that belong to the category/directory.
My `index.php` checks if one of this virtual directories exist and then sends visitor to the correct path or page.
Now my problem, I have restricted access to all physical directories in my plesk panel, so that if you try to access one of them you will get 403 issued by server rather then custom that can looks like the rest of my site. So how would I check for all physical directory existence in my `index.php`? is there any PHP function that will do just this?
Kind regards

Comment: Just curious, when you say "virtual directory" do you mean rewrite using htaccess rewrites?

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, this is exactly what I meant to say :)

Comment: @Cfreak will check in few minutes and get back to you on this one. Thanks

Comment: Yes, what @Cfreak says is correct.  Use file_exists() to detect if a file exists, or use is_dir() to check if a folder exists.